# Multiply subtotoal price in minicart

Tags: magento2, javascript, html, knockoutjs, mini-cart

I want to show two subtotal prices in the minicart. The plan is to multiply the subtotal price and print it next to the original subtotal price. The price is printed by knockout in the html file `magento/vendor/magento/module-tax/view/frontend/web/template/checkout/minicart/subtotal/totals.html` which looks like this:

```
<!--
/**
 * Copyright © 2013-2017 Magento, Inc. All rights reserved.
 * See COPYING.txt for license details.
 */
-->

<div class="amount price-container">
    <!-- ko if: displaySubtotal() -->
        <!-- ko if: display_cart_subtotal_excl_tax -->
            <span class="price-wrapper" data-bind="html: cart().subtotal_excl_tax"></span>
        <!-- /ko -->

        <!-- ko if: !display_cart_subtotal_excl_tax && display_cart_subtotal_incl_tax -->
            <span class="price-wrapper" data-bind="html: cart().subtotal_incl_tax"></span>
        <!-- /ko -->

        <!-- ko if: !display_cart_subtotal_excl_tax && !display_cart_subtotal_incl_tax -->
            <span class="price-wrapper price-including-tax"
                  data-bind="attr: { 'data-label': $t('Incl. Tax') }, html: cart().subtotal_incl_tax">
            </span>

            <span class="price-wrapper price-excluding-tax"
                  data-bind="attr: { 'data-label': $t('Excl. Tax') }, html: cart().subtotal_excl_tax">
            </span>
        <!-- /ko -->
    <!-- /ko -->
    <!-- ko ifnot: displaySubtotal() -->
        <!-- ko foreach: getRegion('minicart-subtotal-hidden') -->
            <!-- ko template: getTemplate() --><!-- /ko -->
        <!-- /ko -->
    <!-- /ko -->
 </div>
```

I can't figure out where (in which file and how) `data-bind="html: cart().subtotal_excl_tax"` gets the subtotal. Is what I am doing trying to do possible or is there a better way of accomplishing this?

Comment: I don't have time to look into it fully but this file may be responsible for the `cart()` function - https://github.com/magento/magento2/blob/99e85cbc45223baa3551e4c534b650c0d2c6358b/app/code/Magento/Tax/view/frontend/web/js/view/checkout/minicart/subtotal/totals.js

Answer (score 0):

I would suggest to debug below files and it's function:

```
**getSectionData**  function from **Magento\Checkout\CustomerData\Cart.php** 
**afterGetSectionData** function from **Magento\Tax\Plugin\Checkout\CustomerData\Cart.php**
Magento\Weee\Plugin\Checkout\CustomerData\Cart.php
```

Hope this helps...